# Dynamic class field creation before metaclass machinery

Tags: python, dynamic

I'm trying to get rid of `exec` in a code similar to this:

```
class A(object):
    for field in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        exec '%s = "%s value"' % (field, field)
```

...so that:

```
>>> A.one
'one value'
>>> A.two
'two value'
>>> A.three
'three value'
```

EDIT: and also the requirement mentioned in the subject is met i.e. `A.one` is `'one value'`, before `A` is instantiated (not to be mistaken for `A()` instantiated).

Is there a way?

Comment: Can you explain what the heading has to do with the question?

Comment: This is icky. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @gnibbler Yes. I'm trying to do that before class is instantiated. So that metaclass that is called upon refering to A already works on those dynamically created fields.

Comment: @katrielalex I thought it's more readable than having to use django.forms.BaseForm and calling type()... but the question seemed interesting in itself. I first thought I wouldn't be able to execute for loop in `A`'s body, but when I discovered it's possible, I wanted to go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> values = 'one', 'two', 'three'
>>> A = type('A', (object,), {i: i + ' value' for i in values})
>>> A.one
'one value'
>>> A.three
'three value'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [the `setattr` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
class A(object):
  pass

for field in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
  setattr(A, field, field + ' value')
```

Comment: I should have repeated the requirement from the subject... although now I'm not sure if it holds for the version with `exec`.

Comment: I tested it and the version with `exec` is executed before `__metaclass__.__new__()`... I also tried putting setattr() inside `A` before posting, but it didn't work as `A` is not defined yet.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just inherit from the metaclass and do it there

```
class MyMetaClass(MetaClass):
    def __new__(meta, classname, baseclasses, classdict):
        fields = classdict['__myfields__']
        for field in fields:
            classdict[field] = field + ' value'
        del classDict['__myfields__']
        MetaClass.__new__(meta, classname, baseclasses, classdict)
```

Then you can just do:

```
class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
    __myfields__ = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to generate something dynamically that the metaclass can process. There's a very simple way to achieve that without resorting to hackery like `exec`. All you have to do is think of this in a different way: modify the metaclass so that the names are generated there.

```
class AutoFieldMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, d):
        for field in d.get('AUTOFIELDS', ()):
            d[field] = field + ' value'
        return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, d)

class A(object, metaclass=AutoFieldMeta):
    AUTOFIELDS = ('one', 'two', 'three')

>>> A.one
'one value'
>>>
```

and if you don't want to modify the existing metaclass you can subclass it.

Comment: beat me by 33 seconds but I'll spend the extra time for quality;)

Comment: This does the job, it deserves +1, but I'm still here waiting in hope that you can do it in three clear lines like the original code and without `exec`. If only there was a way to call `=` (statements...).

Comment: If you ignore the metaclass definition then it's only two lines and they're clearer than the original. You *can* do it trivially in the same number of lines as your original without using exec, but you really don't want to go down that route [in a class body you can assign to `vars()/locals()` and unlike assigning to `locals()` in a function it will actually work, probably, this week]. `vars()[field] = "%s value" % field`

Comment: Metaclass is good for declarative programming from provider's perspective. Then you are _interpreting_ class content (it still looks cumbersome to me, but that's not something you have to care about as user).

What I'm trying to say is that maybe class body _should_ (_and has not yet_) become the one obvious place for modifications at creation time. You should be able to use language power for this.

It's like a difference between syntax and semantics. Using metaclasses, you act on semantics, I need to act on syntax. The semantics are provided by Django already and I don't want to interfere.

Comment: You are of course right that this is not standardized and is not guaranteed to work next week.

Answer (score 1):

This works too and I think it's a happy end...

```
class A(object):
    for a in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        locals().update({a: a + ' value'})
```

And for anyone searching for assignment expression in Python, this is in the same mood as aaronasterling answer :):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/202234-assignment-in-expression/

Comment: Or if you wanted a one liner: `vars().update((field, field + " value") for field in ('one', 'two', 'three'))` ick

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this by saying that this is incredibly hackish but eliminates the exec. We just stick the attributes on the current stack frame as the code in the class statement is being executed. It is only guaranteed to work on CPython and there are warnings against doing it in the manual. I would highly recommend that you go with duncans metaclass solution.

```
import sys

class A(object):
    for field in ['one', 'two', 'three']:
        sys._getframe().f_locals[field] = field + ' value'
```